# How to speed up the Grad-CAM calculation within a loop in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, heatmap

I'm coding an hand-crafted solution to compute the Grad-CAM for each image contained in a given dataset.
Here is the code:

```
def grad_cam(model, image, _class, layer_name, channel_index):

    class_output  = model.output[:, _class]
    conv_output_layer = model.get_layer(layer_name).output

    gradients = K.gradients(class_output, conv_output_layer)[0] 
    grad_function = K.function([model.input], [conv_output_layer, gradients])
    output, grad_val = grad_function([image]) # <== Execution time bottleneck

    #code...
    return grad_cam
```

Given an image, a convolutional layer and a channel index, the aim is to understand where a CNN classifier is looking at, reason why Grad-CAM representation has to be computed for all dataset's images. Since the dataset provides tens of thousand images, `grad_cam()` function is called within a loop:

```
def visual_attention(df):
    #code...
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        #code...
        heatmap = grad_cam(model, df[i], _class, layer_name, channel_index)
        #code...
    #code...
```

where `df` stands for the entire dataset. Even if the previously mentioned code works pretty good, I noticed a slowdown involving `grad_cam()` function since `K.gradients()` builds a new back-propagation graph each time it's called. I did many attempts to try to manage this situation but TensorFlow continues to add new nodes to its graph after each iteration. After a few hundred of iterations, code becomes embarrassingly slow. How to deal with this situation? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split the creation of the `grad_function` function and use it independently, for example:

```
def grad_cam(model, _class, layer_name, channel_index):

    class_output  = model.output[:, _class]
    conv_output_layer = model.get_layer(layer_name).output

    gradients = K.gradients(class_output, conv_output_layer)[0] 
    grad_function = K.function([model.input], [conv_output_layer, gradients])

    return return grad_function
```

Then you create an instance of the grad function only once:

```
grad_fn = grad_cam(model, _class, layer_name, channel_index)
```

And then call this function in a loop:

```
def visual_attention(df):
    #code...
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        #code...
        heatmap = grad_fn(df[i])
        #code...
    #code...
```